# Domain url redirect with myDNS

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, redirect, url

I have a domain and want to redirect this domain to url (for example www.example.com). How I can do this with mydns (using mydnsconfig interface or mydns itself).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for an HTTP forward or redirect, which is performed by the web server, not the DNS server: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection .

Otherwise, create a CNAME record as follows:

```
your.domain.com. IN CNAME other.domain.net.
```